# How to prevent MacOS to change focus on other monitors when I'm switching Spaces or clicking on a window

Tags: window-manager, spaces

I have seen this question before but everyone seems to say that it's not a bug, but a feature. I beg to disagree and provide my problem and perspective:

I have Chrome spread between two Spaces in different displays (native and external). I have terminals and Chrome 1 (playing youtube) on the single Space in the native display, and I have two spaces on the external display, one with vscode and other with Chrome 2 (with documentation, github PRs, etc).

Whenever I sweep from my code to the docs window my terminals are replaced by the Chrome in that space (which I don't want, because I can see what's happening there because of Stage Manager providing a small preview of the app, if something interesting happens there I can manually focus on it).

Is there any configuration or external application that allows me to override this behaviour of "clicking" on a window and bringing all the app's windows to focus? You see, I'm not "alt-tabbing" to the app*, to bring focus to the APP, I'm clicking on a window, to get focus on that window, specifically.

** = thus the AltTab app solution doesn't work in this case*

Comment: This is a wild guess but under Desktop & Dock in System Settings, have you tried toggling "when switching to an application, switch to a Space with open windows for this application" to whatever is besides the current option? Maybe it only targets "app switching" as in alt-tab, but maybe it would help. [I've never been sure what this setting does lol]

Comment: Just tried it here, it doesn't work :/

Comment: Thank you for this. God, how much I hate this behavior. I just don't understand the logic behind it or why it can't be turned off.